# Hide a marker in Google Maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am loading a bunch of markers based on a dataset that I am reading from Mongodb in my ejs file. I just loop through the markers to add them to the map and then a "click" eventlistener to display some comment for each marker in the infowindow:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
<%for (i = 0; i < <%=comments.length%>; i++) {%>
   var LatLng = {lat: <%=comments[i].lat, lng: <%=comments[i].lng%>};
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map:map,
        title: 'Click to see comment details',
        id:'<%=comments[i]._id%>'
    });
    marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
           var contentString = `
              <div class="comment-item">
                <div id="bodyContent">
                  <p class="lead mt-2"><%=comments[i].textComment%></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <form style="display: inline" method="POST" action="/admin/comments/<%=comments[i]._id%>" class="approve-comment-form">
                  <input type="submit" value="Approve Comment" class="btn btn-success"/>
                 </form>
               </div>
          `
          infowindow.setContent(contentString);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
    })(marker, i));
<%}%>
```

What I am trying to do is to submit the form (approve the comment) using ajax code below. This basically, updates a field for that comment in my Mongodb document.

```
$(document).on('submit','.approve-comment-form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var editCommentData = $(this).serialize();
        var editCommentAction = $(this).attr('action');
        var $originalCommentItem = $(this).parent('.comment-item');
        $.ajax({
            url: editCommentAction,
            data: editCommentData,
            type: 'PUT',
            originalItem: $originalCommentItem,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    })
```

So, the form submission works well and if I refresh the page, that marker will not be displayed on the map (Because the "ajax put" method toggles a switch from on to off for that marker and on page reload it won't be displayed), but the problem is that I want the marker to hide also with the form submit (Without the page refresh) so that I know I have already approved the comment inside it.

Comment: You show a infoWindow when click a marker  ..  so why you want hide the marker ?? ..  your question is not clear..

Comment: Do you want to hide/remove the marker when the infowindow is closed, from a button/link in the infowindow, or a different click event (rightclick/double click)?  Or do you want the infowindow to open and the marker to hide on the original click?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a specific marker when a button on the infowindow is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573004/how-to-remove-a-specific-marker-when-a-button-on-the-infowindow-is-clicked)

Comment: scaisEdge: I wanted to simplify my question, but there is a form inside the infowindow and I want to hide the marker after the form is submitted. I don't want to reload the map after the form submission since Google Maps API is not free and charges by number of loads

Comment: @geocodezip well actually I have a form inside the infowindow and I want the marker to hide when the form is submitted. I am using ajax to submit the form and to avoid a refresh of Google Maps. I can't do the form submission and the marker hiding at the same time.

Comment: Hide the marker after the form is submitted.  If that is what you are trying to do and it isn't working, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (the posted code/question doesn't contain the form or how it is being submitted; or any indication that is what you were trying to do).

Comment: Just updated the post